# Current month in Calendar view

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm sure this would be something very easy but I'm unable to sort it out.
I'm using a calendar view in ASP.Net and have to apply a check as follows.

```
if (Calendar1.TodaysDate.Month == e.Day.Date.Month)
{
}
```

Instead of using TodaysDate I want the month that is currently displaying on the view i.e. its Febraury right now and when I click the ***Next*** icon to display March it still has Feb in Calendar1.TodaysDate.Month (because the current date is in Feb. What property can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month gets the date of the visible month